# how to set bootstrap to be vertical

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem, i need one more box on the left side below the yellow box

[image]

i use this code for the bootstrap

```html
<div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:yellow">
   a<br>b<br>c<br>d
   </div>
```

anyone know how to make one more box but vertical? i have no idea about this :(

Comment: Can you provide working example of whole form not just left div. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap 4.

you can add a wrapper around the element, make the wrapper a flex container and flex vertically using `flex-column`

using bootstrap classes

```
<div class="col-md-3 d-flex flex-column">
  <div style="background-color:yellow">
    a<br>b<br>c<br>d
  </div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid blue">
    1<br>2
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/YEwjLp

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it like this?

I've added a `div` with the `id` `wrapper` and gave it `float: left` and the `form-div` `float: right`. You already made it that the `divs` are placed next to each other, so you just need to add a "wrapper" `div` and place the other box inside of it.

```css
#wrapperLeft {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
}

#leftOne {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#leftTwo {
  background-color: green;
}

#right {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapperLeft">
  <div id="leftOne">
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>
  </div>
  <div id="leftTwo">
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="right">
  some forms
  <input/><br/>
  form<br/>
  form<br/>
  form<br/>
  form<br/>
  form<br/>
  form<br/>
  form<br/>
  form<br/>
  form<br/>
  form<br/>
  form<br/>
form<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your code will work, but I've found an easier answer